# Macro (VBA) in Excel is failing on colleagues PC but works on mine when colleague is logged in

Tags: vba, excel

I'm developing VBA tools to automate a series of long winded administration tasks, the code runs fine in the following circumstances.

- When I am logged into my PC
- When my colleague is logged into my PC
- When I am logged into my colleagues PC

However it fails to complete correctly, when my colleague runs it on her PC.

The specific area it is failing in is:

```
'creates 2 dims for location of the two files that need opening based on the critera set on the home page

Dim newdata As String
newdata = Range("f11").Value
Dim olddata As String
olddata = Range("f12").Value
Dim fileextension As String
fileextension = Range("f14").Value

Dim fulllocationolddata As String
fulllocationolddata = Range("f13") & olddata & fileextension

Dim fulllocationnewdata As String
fulllocationnewdata = Range("f13") & newdata & fileextension


'open file containing OLDDATA c&p previous days data to the conversion tool
'then shuts the old data workbook

  Workbooks.Open Filename:=fulllocationolddata
  Workbooks(olddata).Activate
  Worksheets("sheet1").Select
  Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

  Workbooks("Stockfile Conversion Tool.xlsm").Activate
  Sheets("OLD STOCK").Activate
  Range("A3").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial

    Workbooks(olddata).Activate
    Worksheets("sheet1").Select

  Workbooks(olddata).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

The final line (Workbooks(olddata).Close SaveChanges:=False) does not shut the workbook, then later in the macro I open another workbook of the same name but as it's already open it just activates the window and the rest of the code falls apart.

If anyone has any ideas where I'm going wrong it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Plan303

Comment: Do you use a `On Error Resume Next` earlier in the code somewhere? This might be hiding the problem.

Comment: It would be much easier for you to debug if you weren't using so many `.Activate` and `.Select` methods throughout your code. You also don't need to use `Copy`/`Paste` you can just set cell values to those of other cells, e.g. `Workbook("ExampleWB").Sheets("ExampleSheet").Range("A1").Value = Workbook("ExampleWB2).Sheets("ExampleSheet2").Range("A1").Value`

Comment: @CLR yes I do, earlier in the code I have a section that clears existing data and filters and I use On Error Resume Next to skip if there is no filters.

Comment: You need to `On Error Goto 0` once that's done to stop the error that is preventing the workbook closure from being hidden. That should tell you what you need to know or post here for further help.

Comment: I've removed the start section of code where it clears out data and removed all the on error resume next code.  Now I get a "run time error '9'" subscript out of range. Message boxz

Comment: Replace all `Workbooks(olddata)` with `Workbooks(olddata & fileextension)` and try then.

Comment: Hi Axel,  thanks for your input.  I've made that adjustment and it hasn't helped.  the part that is really baffaling me is that it works fine on my PC just not on my colleagues PC when she is logged in as the user (the IT department here are trying to convince me the problem is with my code and not the user profles or anything), but if I log in on the PC is runs through without a hitch...

Comment: If `olddata`only contains the name of the workbook and not the file extension (`.xlsm` for example) then `Workbooks(olddata)` will only work if `Hide extensions for known file types` is set in `Folder Options`. It will fail, if that option is not set and the file extensions are visible in Explorer. But `Workbooks("Stockfile Conversion Tool.xlsm")` will always work and so `Workbooks(olddata & fileextension)` should also work if `olddata` only contains the name of the workbook and `fileextension` contains `.xlsm` for example.

Comment: Hi all,  Just wanted to thank you all for your suggestions and confirm this is now fixed.  The solution suggested by @AxelRichter  corrected it.  I had to go through the entire script and at every stage declared the file extension i.e  Workbooks("Stockfile Conversion Tool" & ".xlsm").Activate  once again.. thanks for the suppport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comments to an answer here:

Whether `Workbooks("Name of the Workbook")` is working or not depends on the settings in **System control** - **Folder Options** - **View** - **[ x ] Hide extensions for known file types**.

If this is set, then Excel's file extensions `.xlsx`, `.xlsm`, ... are **not** visible in Explorer or other file listings. Only the file names of the Excel files are visible. If so, then `Workbooks("Name of the Workbook")` will work.

If `Hide extensions for known file types` is not set, then Excel's file extensions `.xlsx`, `.xlsm`, ... **are** visible in Explorer or other file listings. If so, then `Workbooks("Name of the Workbook")` will **not** work. Then only `Workbooks("Name of the Workbook.xlsx")`, giving the name **and** the extension, will work.

But `Workbooks("Name of the Workbook.xlsx")` will also work if `Hide extensions for known file types` **is** set. So using the full name inclusive extension should be preferred.

So for the concrete question:

If `olddata` only contains the name of the workbook and not the file extension then `Workbooks(olddata)` will only work if `Hide extensions for known file types` is set in `Folder Options`. It will fail, if that option is not set and the file extensions are visible in Explorer. But `Workbooks("Stockfile Conversion Tool.xlsm")` will always work independent of whether `Hide extensions for known file types` is set or not. So `Workbooks(olddata & fileextension)` should also always work if `olddata` only contains the name of the workbook and `fileextension` contains `.xlsx` for example.